# Strange behaviour of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathemtaica correctly computes the following definite integral:

```
Integrate[(q Log[q]^3)/(1 - q), {q, 0, 1}]    
(* Out: 6 - \[Pi]^4/15*)
```

But, when I change the denominator a little bit:

```
Integrate[(q Log[q]^3)/(-1 + q), {q, 0, 1}]    
(* Out: 0*)
```

The output is idetically zero, which is obviously incorrect. Why? (I am using Mathematica 12.1.)

Comment: Mathematica 12.2 : ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj3zp.png)

Comment: This worked in 11.3 and 12.1; did you try this on a fresh kernel?

Comment: I have also verified the results that @Nasser provided in the previous comment. My version is 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)

Comment: BTSI? (Bug That Squished Itself)

Comment: Works for Version 12.1 on Windows

Comment: This is a samle of my Mathematica notebook:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEXnu.png
After comple of other computations, it has started to give wrong results even for $1-q$